# Sort array of dates to nearest date

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have an array of different dates. 
Lets say
`const arr = ['21. may', '01. jan', '05. feb', '07. jun', '20. dec']`

I want the dates in order, of the date closest to the date today. So in this case (18. marts), the output should be
`const arr = ['21. may', '07. jun', '20. dec', '01. jan', '05. feb']`

Is this even possible, when the year is not included?

Comment: Please provide code, what did you try ?

Comment: Yes it is possible. You just need to define whatever closeness metric you want. Can you write a function that outputs how close any of these dates is to today?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to order the dates by distance to today with passed dates (negative distances) appearing last, you can do this:

```js
const arr = ['21. may', '01. jan', '05. feb', '07. jun', '20. dec'];

const today = new Date('2019/03/18'); // use new Date() for current day

arr.sort((a, b) => toDate(a) - toDate(b));

function toDate(str) {
  const monthNames = ['jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'apr', 'may', 'jun', 'jul', 'aug', 'sep', 'oct', 'nov', 'dec'];
  const [day, monthName] = str.split(/\.\s*/);
  const month = monthNames.indexOf(monthName.toLowerCase());
  const date = new Date(today.getFullYear(), month, +day);
  if (date < today) date.setFullYear(date.getFullYear() + 1);
  return date;
}

console.log(arr); // ["21. may", "07. jun", "20. dec", "01. jan", "05. feb"]
```

Comment: This is so close to be the right answer. Unfortunately, it outputs february to be closets. Thats not what I what it to be, since we passed february

Comment: @jonask, in terms of absolute distance february is the closest, what distance metric do you need ?

Comment: Well, "soonest to the next date"

Comment: @jonask, I fixed it by adding a year to passed dates and then doing the comparison

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: This answer is wrong. To compute the distance, you need to add `Math.abs(…)`. Currently you are just sorting the dates in ascending order.

Comment: @Bergi, I add a year to the past dates, so the distance is always positive and the past dates are at the end. My previous answer used the Math.abs() trick but was not handling past dates well

Comment: That just treats "01. jan" and "05. feb" as referring to dates in next year. It has nothing to do with their distance to today. You could omit the `- today.getTime()` from your code and it wouldn't change the outcome. Maybe this is what the OP actually wanted, but it's nothing to do with distances. 5th of February is closer to today than 1st of January.

Comment: @Bergi, I agree this is not the distance as in absolute distance, which is what I gave the OP first, but I modified it to move the past dates to the end since the OP asked for it. Distance is relative to the metric you use, which the OP didn't define clearly in his question, but clarified in the comments here.

Comment: @Bergi, thanks for pointing out the getTime() error, I simplified the code

Comment: @jo_va Ah ok. And thanks for the edit, that's what I was just about to suggest :-) One might even move the `setFullYear()` call into the `toDate`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that there are no years in your dates data, you can try this:

```
function sortDateStrArrayFrom(dayAndMonth, array) {
    const dateFrom = new Date(dayAndMonth);

    const datesBefore = [];
    const datesEqual = [];
    const datesAfter = [];

    array.forEach(dateStr => {
        const date = new Date(dateStr);

        if (date < dateFrom) {
            datesBefore.push(dateStr);
        }

        if (date === dateFrom) {
            datesEqual.push(dateStr);
        }

        if (date > dateFrom) {
            datesAfter.push(dateStr);
        }
    })

    return [...datesEqual, ...datesAfter, ...datesBefore];
}

const arr = ['21. may', '01. jan', '05. feb', '07. jun', '20. dec'];

sortDateStrArrayFrom('18. mar', arr); // ["21. may", "07. jun", "20. dec", "01. jan", "05. feb"]
```

If you need, it can be modified with date as input param or setting the same year for every date to work regardless of the year

Comment: This would break if the strings before or after were not in the right order. For example if June appeared before May.

Answer (score 0):

If you add the string `'2019'` onto the end of your date strings, JavaScript's [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) constructor will parse it as being in this year. Once you have a bunch of Date objects, it's easy enough to [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) your strings, and use [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) to get the first one that is in the future:

```
const dates = ['21. may', '01. jan', '05. feb', '07. jun', '20. dec'];

const sorted = [...dates].sort((a, b) => new Date(a) - new Date(b));
const soonest = sorted.findIndex(date => new Date(`${date} 2019`) > new Date());

const soonestDates = [...sorted.slice(soonest), ...sorted.slice(0, soonest)];
console.log(soonestDates);  // ["21. may", "07. jun", "20. dec", "01. jan", "05. feb"]
```